# Processing sql xevents in c#, missing an assembly

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to process SQL XEvents from an `.xel` file in a c# console app. According to [This Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/extended_events/2011/07/20/introducing-the-extended-events-reader/) I need to add a reference to `Microsoft.SqlServer.XEvent.Linq.dll` but I haven't been able to find it. What am I missing?

Comment: A quick google search seems to show that it is part of the SQL Server Management Objects. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676  There is a MSI in there called SharedManagementObjects that may have what you want.

Comment: Looks like I already have that installed, I reinstalled it to be sure, but the .dll seems to be still missing.

Comment: OK, so I wasn't able to get visual studio to list it as an available assembly. But I did find the DLL in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Shared` and manually included it in my project, and so far that seems to be working.

Comment: Oh yea. It's 50/50 chance Microsoft will register their stuff to show up in Visual Studio's reference lists. Should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I wasn't able to get visual studio to list it as an available assembly. But I did find the DLL in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Shared` and manually included it in my project, and so far that seems to be working.

As [TyCobb suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47930742/processing-sql-xevents-in-c-missing-an-assembly#comment82830643_47930742) You might also need the SQL Server Management Objects.

Note: `Microsoft.SqlServer.XE.Core.dll` is also required